# Binding InCallService

Tags: java, android

I'm currently developing a calling app and I've run into an issue regarding InCallService. I need to bind it to my CallActivity in order for features like speakerphone, microphone mute etc to work. The problem is that when I do bind it (following Google documentations on binding services), onCallAdded never gets called. How should I bind the InCallService?

Here's how it's currently done:

InCallService:

```
package com.;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telecom.Call;
import android.telecom.InCallService;
import timber.log.Timber;

public class CallService extends InCallService {

    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        CallService getService() {
            return CallService.this;
        }
    }

    public void testing() {
        Timber.e("IT WORKS");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
        Timber.e("ADD");
        super.onCallAdded(call);
        new OngoingCall().setCall(call);
        CallActivity.start(this, call);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallRemoved(Call call) {
        Timber.e("REMOVE");
        super.onCallRemoved(call);
        new OngoingCall().setCall(null);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        //return super.onBind(intent);
        Timber.e("BIND");
        return binder;
    }

}
```

CallActivity ServiceConnection:

```
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        CallService.LocalBinder binder = (CallService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

onStart:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
    bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System is trying to bind to your service as well and `InCallService` `onBind` implementation is not empty.

You have to call through to `super.onBind(intent)` or your call service won't work properly. Add custom intent action to your `bindService` intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CallService.class);
intent.setAction("DirectBind");
bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

And resolve it in the service:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Timber.e("BIND by "+ intent); // log what intent is trying to bind to your service
    if (intent.getAction() == "DirectBind") {
        return binder;
    }
    return super.onBind(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. Tried it and works flawlessly.

Comment: @andres-h1 can you please share your complete code on rizwan.rasheed@surveyauto.com i want to have a same implementation. but i am facing an issue.